# WordPress : query by attachment meta (image size)

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to use `WP_Query` to get attachment images by pixel size?

For example all images with a width of 500px and height of 300px. Or images with a height bigger than 300px.

As far as i can see i can catch this data in the meta query with `'key' => '_wp_attachment_metadata'` but what then? There seems no solution that is precise enough to target that width or height inside `_wp_attachment_metadata` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it with wp_query as height and width do not have their own meta field (they are part of a serialized array). But this is easy enough to overcome, we can just assign them their own postmeta db entry when uploading (you can also use wp_query to get all images and loop over to update existing images)

```
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'add_metac', 10, 2);


function add_metac($meta, $id){

    update_post_meta($id, 'height', (int) $meta['height']);
    update_post_meta($id, 'width', (int) $meta['width']);
    return $meta;

}
```

You can then query for images greater than dimensions etc, something like this:

```
$types = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png');
$args= array(
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type'    => $types,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', //-->this is default but showing here as you can use OR
        array(
            'key'     => 'height',
            'value'   => 300,
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'width',
            'value'   => 300,
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
    )

);

$images= new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Great answer thanks. I thought already about doing it like this. Seems like the most useful solution to me ... The initial query could be done with register_activation_hook and query by attachments that don't have postmeta width & height? What is if the postmeta width or height is changed by a plugin or anything (for example a switch this image plugin) ... probably a rare case but is there a hook like wp_update_attachment_metadata?

Answer (score 0):

@Dan is mentioned correctly WP_Query and mysql can't handle this way. But we need a all display media with conditional size above @Dan's answer fit this solution but when we need also pagination parameter and display limit records each page so have solution below change query request.

```
<?php

global $query_args;

$query_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'),
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'fields' => 'ids'
);  // add pagination parameters in $query_args

add_filter( 'posts_request', function( $request ){

 global $wpdb, $query_args;

 remove_filter( 'posts_request', __FUNCTION__ );

 $all_media = $wpdb->get_results($request);

 if( empty( $all_media ) )
 return $request;

 $exclude_ids = array();

 foreach( $all_media as $media ){
     $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $media->ID );
     if( $meta['width'] != 500 ||  $meta['height'] < 300 ) // Add condition also allow add more condition with different sizes
     $exclude_ids[] = $media->ID;
 }   

 if( $exclude_ids ){
   $query_args['post__not_in'] = $exclude_ids;
   $q = new WP_Query( $query_args );
   $request =  $q->request;
   wp_reset_query();      
 }

 return $request;  

});


$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
//echo $query->request;
if( $query->have_posts() ){
  while( $query->have_posts() ){
      $query->the_post();
      echo get_the_title();
  }     

}

wp_reset_query();
```

I didn't tested more records. I hope this helpful for you.

Comment: causes a memory size exhausted error in my enviroment :(

Comment: create a separate function instead php anonymous function like i think filter is not removing second time.
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'my_function_name') and inside body function
remove_filter( 'posts_request', 'my_function_name') ;

Comment: That do the trick. Strangely the query returns first attachments that match the condition and then others that doesn't.

Comment: how many attachments get in your previous query result ? Change condition as your requirement.

Comment: hmm that doesn't seem to work. what this code basically does is: i want 10 (default) attachments. So it pre queries 10 posts and catches all attachments that doesn't match the size condition. Then it tells the query to ignore this or that post/attachment. But if you check 10 and exclude 7 there are only 3 left ... so the new query ignores that 7 attachments and gets the next 7 ... and that next 7 aren't checked.

Comment: As far as i can see i have to run a condition over all attachments to get a list of correct sizes and work with that. Probably via post_in or something ...

Comment: I'm not sure but second query i s get new 10 results with exclude find previous 7 results.