# Display posts where their thumbnail width is smaller then 200px

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to weed out products with small image sizes on my site.
With over 11000 products I cant do this manually so I'm trying to write a custom query to show post's that have thumbnail that has width of 300px or less. I know I can get the size using "getimagesize" and can output the width like below

```
<?php
$image_details = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image_details);
echo $width;
?>
```

But how do add that to $args to only show posts with thumbnails width width smaller then 300px?

```
<?php 
// args
    $args = array(
          'posts_per_page' => 100,
          'post_type' => array('product'),
          'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
          'meta_key'  => '_price',
          'order' => 'DESC',    

          'meta_query'  => array(
          'relation'    => 'AND',
           array(
           'key'     => '_stock',
           'type'    => 'numeric',
           'value'   => 0,
           'compare' => '>'
           ),                               
         )                                      
     );
?>
```

Comment: Does [this help you?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38088630/15040627)